# local Reportviewer parameter display area is not prompt in Asp.net Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewerformvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCyZN.jpg)
i try to set report parameter to the reportviewer control but it seem not work .
no parameter area is displayed.
i'm using reportviewer for mvc from Nuget

my code in view :

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)

my code in controller :

```
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
        reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
        reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        reportViewer.ShowPromptAreaButton = true;
        reportViewer.ShowPrintButton = false;
        reportViewer.PromptAreaCollapsed = true;

        ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("FromDate", "ParamVal");
        reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
```